# In C++, can objects be null?

Tags: c++

Here's what I have done:
I've got a simple class:

```
class Person{
  public:
    Person();
}

And in my main:

int main() {
  Person myPer = NULL;
}
```

This is impossible since C++ does not allow that, however:

```
int main() {
  Person* perPtr = NULL;
  Person myPer = *perPtr; // corrected, it was &perPtr(typo error) before answers
}
```

This compiles fine and as I see I did able to have a NULL object. So isn't it violating the rule that only pointers can be null in C++? Or is there such a rule in C++?
2nd one is after I wrote this code, I added a if statement checking whether myPer is NULL or not but that gave me error. So does it show that C++ does not really like the NULL object idea no matter what you do to make objects NULL...

Comment: `Person myPer = &perPtr;` is a type error. Did you mean `Person myPers = *perPtr;`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're learning C++, I'll give you this most important tip: just because it compiles it does not mean it's valid or that it should work. And similarly just because it compiles and runs as you expected it doesn't mean it's correct either. Yes, C++ is a very harsh language :( I'll recommend [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642).

Comment: "This compiles fine". No, it doesn't. Please copy-paste (not retype) the exact program you compiled.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Um...objects can't be `null` in Java, either. Object *references* can be `null`.

Comment: You should also think seriously about *why* you want an "object to be null". Often (not always, but often) this is a symptom of missing the goal and getting fixated on something that *you* believe is a step towards it, while the actual problem possibly has a much more elegant solution.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Yes, I meant Person myPers = *perPtr; and I have great answers,thanks all...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects cannot be null, only pointers can. Your code is incorrect and does not compile, since its trying to initialize a `Person` from a pointer to a pointer to `Person`. If you were to change your code to

```
Person* perPtr = NULL;
Person myPer = *perPtr;
```

then it would be trying to initialize a `Person` out of a dereferenced null pointer to a `Person`, which is undefined behavior (and most likely a crash).

If you need to use the idioms where an object could be in a `NULL` state, you could use `Boost.Optional`:

```
boost::optional< Person > myPer = boost::none;
if( myPer )
{
    myPer->do_something();
}
```

It's a generalization of what is usually done with pointers, except it does not use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 4):

**This is undefined behaviour.** C++ references cannot be legally set to NULL. If you want a "nullable reference", use a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This is called undefined behavior. Unexpected results may happen when you attempt to dereference `NULL` or get the address of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

References are basically syntactically nicer way of saying pointers.

Comment: There's a hair more than just syntax, but only a hair.  A reference cannot legally be NULL, nor can it be reset.

Comment: I was just cautious, since there's a lot of people who think that references are pointers with syntactic sugar, and then end up dereferencing NULL pointers all over.

Comment: I see, the point of my answer was provide an intuitive understanding of what has *actually happened*, not how to use references.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class that has "NULL" state.

E.g. a class that owns something else, such as a file handle or a window handle or anything else, such that it can be empty or not.

You can see this with any string class or with any container class.

if (x.empty()) ...

But the concept of "is null" is limited to pointers and smart pointers (or any class that you override to support such use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have a NULL object in C++. Your first attempt is trying to set an object equal to a pointer, and thus fails.

You can have a NULL pointer, and references are simply pointers with slightly different syntax.

You can de-reference a NULL pointer (as in the compiler will let you), but that's undefined behavior. If you're lucky, dereferencing NULL will crash, so you know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say the following *is impossible since C++ does not allow* it:

```
int main() {
  Person myPer = NULL;
}
```

It is possible, and C++ does allow it. It all depends on how you've defined the class`Person`. For example,  if the class `Person` has a constructor as shown below:

```
class Person
{
  public:
    Person(char *) {}
};
```

then `Person myPer = NULL` will compile just fine : http://www.ideone.com/586Pf

Now how much useful such class can be is up to you. One may exploit the above fact, and may come up with cool and useful (utility) class.